# Fullscreen python program

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, fullscreen

how to create a full screen software on python on ubuntu system without any close button or any other menu bars...also how to bind a hotkey so that when i press it it exits full screen...it could be like pressing F11 in webbrowsers to make it full screen....please help
i have already tried the following code answered in a similar question but the problem is than menubars and close button still persists...

```
class FullScreenApp(object):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master=master
        pad=3
        self._geom='500x240+0+0'
        master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            master.winfo_screenwidth()-pad, master.winfo_screenheight()-pad))
        master.bind('<Escape>',self.toggle_geom)            
    def toggle_geom(self,event):
        geom=self.master.winfo_geometry()
        print(geom,self._geom)
        self.master.geometry(self._geom)
        self._geom=geom
```